# Keep GridView sorted after index change

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I got my gridview and I run the event sorting on header click , like this:

```
 protected void GridViewFoundations_Sorting1(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = GridViewFoundations.DataSource as DataTable;

                if (dataTable != null)
                {
                    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
                    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

                    GridViewFoundations.DataSource = dataView;
                    GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
                }

            }

private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    newSortDirection = "ASC";
                    break;

                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    newSortDirection = "DESC";
                    break;
            }

            return newSortDirection;
        }
```

**Now I've two problems :**

1) I click on the column header but it only shorts as "ASC" can anyone tell me why ?
2) How can i keep the sorting even when client change pages?

Bind grid function (i have some filters)

```
protected void BindGridFilters()
        {
            if (tb_fondeName.Text != "" && tb_fondeId.Text == "")
            {

                string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
                string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsDocument.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  and templateId=3094 and text like '%" + tb_fondeName.Text + "%' group by cmsDocument.nodeId,text";

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);



                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
                GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
                GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
            }
            if (tb_fondeId.Text != "" && tb_fondeName.Text == "")
            {

                string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
                string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsDocument.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  and templateId=3094 and cmsDocument.nodeId = " + Convert.ToInt32(tb_fondeId.Text) + " group by cmsDocument.nodeId,text";

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);



                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
                GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
                GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
            }
            if (tb_fondeId.Text != "" && tb_fondeName.Text != "")
            {

                string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
                string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsDocument.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  and templateId=3094 and cmsDocument.nodeId = " + Convert.ToInt32(tb_fondeId.Text) + " and text like '%" + tb_fondeName.Text + "%' group by cmsDocument.nodeId,text";

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);



                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
                sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
                GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
                GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
            }
            if (tb_fondeName.Text == "" && tb_fondeId.Text == "")
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property GridSortDirection

```
protected string GridSortDirection
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["GridSortDirection"] != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(ViewState["GridSortDirection"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["GridSortDirection"] = value;
            }
        }
```

On page load provide a default sort direction

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       this.GridSortDirection= "ASC";// setting default value 
    }
}
```

now before providing datasource to grid and binding the grid, add following lines and bind like this

```
 SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
 DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
 sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
 //added 2 lines
 DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
 dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(GridSortDirection);
 GridViewFoundations.DataSource = dataView;
 GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
```

And now to change sort direction create a function

```
private string ChangeSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    newSortDirection = "DESC";
                    break;

                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    newSortDirection = "ASC";
                    break;
            }

            return newSortDirection;
        }
```

And call this function in `GridViewFoundations_Sorting1` like this

```
protected void GridViewFoundations_Sorting1(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable dataTable = GridViewFoundations.DataSource as DataTable;

                if (dataTable != null)
                {
                    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
                    this.GridSortDirection=ChangeSortDirection(e.SortDirection);
                    dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GridSortDirection;

                    GridViewFoundations.DataSource = dataView;
                    GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
                }

            }
```